# Newbie view model issue.. to subclass or not to subclass

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok dead basic question, I'm a self taught developer so often I seem to have gaps where I can't decide which was is the right way... and this is one of them!! Simple I have a view model which has a collection of child items. But where these classes are defined I can't decide if the child object should be a subclass of the parent...

For example this:

```
public class ActionChartViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ActionChartItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    public TextPagingInfo TextPagingInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ActionChartItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string AssignedToUserName { get; set; }
    public string ContactRequested { get; set; }
    public bool Resolved { get; set; }
    public int NoteCount { get; set; }
    public string ContactDetails { get; set; }
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
}
```

Or this:

```
public class ActionChartViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public TextPagingInfo TextPagingInfo { get; set; }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string AssignedToUserName { get; set; }
        public string ContactRequested { get; set; }
        public bool Resolved { get; set; }
        public int NoteCount { get; set; }
        public string ContactDetails { get; set; }
        public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I prefer the second one for a code readability and simplicity front, but I don't know the pros and cons of subclasses. What would you guys think??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In your sample, you say "subclass" but you should say "inner class" (a subclass is a class that inherits from another). Personally, I rarely use inner classes (sometimes I use private classes) and keep all the classes in separate files.

Comment: ahh ok, yeah the sub class vs inner class thing makes sense now. From a technical perspective is there any different with the above 2 examples? I do keep all my entity classes in separate files, but for view model related things I have been keeping all the viewmodel classes associated with one view in a single file which seemed to make better sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use separate classes (in same file) as opposed to an inner class. Inner class would be useful when it serves only the parent class, i.e. would not be accessed from outside of the parent class, only by the parent class methods, etc. In your case the inner class needs to be used on view(s), so I don't see a need for it. The first option, i.e. separate classes, is actually simpler to me and reads better.

Comment: Additionally, by going with the first example provided, you already have a ViewModel for the Details/Edit screen.  If more properties are needed for the Details/Edit, you can use inheritance as the answer from Felipe shows

Answer (score 1):

"SubClass" is when you create more concrete implementations (inherits) of its types. As @ bloparod says, you're doing "inner classes". I also rarely use inner classes. Sometimes I use some `private` or `internal` classe as a temporary. If you do that, you will need to create with the sintaxe like:

```
ActionChartViewModel.Item item = new ActionChartViewModel.Item();
```

I usually separete files and use `public` classes but sometimes when I have lots and lots of ViewModel, I think a good pratice is to keep all of the same category of ViewModels on a single file and inherited when necessary, for sample:

**File:** ProductViewModel.cs

```
public class ProductViewModel 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
   public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDetailViewModel : ProductViewModel 
{
   public int Stocke { get; set; }
   public string Obs { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<ProductMovViewModel> Inventory 
   /* other properties */
}

public class ProductMovViewModel 
{
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public DateTime Date { get; set;
   public int Amout { get; set; }
}
```

As a good pratice too you can separete in files your ViewModels, as you prefer.